# running out of memory with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, out-of-memory

I'm helping make a book app using android studio. The book consists of 35 images which each have a file size of about 4.8MB (SEE EDIT). We're currently handling them by using tabbed activities and creating a fragment for each page. But this means all the fragments (all 35 images) are being handled at the same time which is causing problems with memory. I can get 16 images on my phone before android studio crashes and the other person on the project can get 33 images shown on his laptop using an emulator.

We have 35 java classes that follow this template:

```
package com.example.leesie.bookautism;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by leesie on 23/08/2017.
 */

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

    private Button btnTEST1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment,container,false);

        btnTEST1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTEST1);

        btnTEST1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

who's xml file would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Tab1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textTab1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Tab1ImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/tab1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnTEST1"
        android:text="TESTBTN 1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The main activity is:

```
        package com.example.leesie.bookautism;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    //import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    //import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    //import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    //import android.view.View;
    //import android.view.ViewGroup;
    //import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");

    /* In case we need a toolbar THIS OR THAT
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    */

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    /* In case we need tabs THIS OR THAT
    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    */

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CoverFragment(), "COVER");
    adapter.addFragment(new CopyrightFragment(), "COPYRIGHT");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "TAB2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "TAB3");
    ...
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab33Fragment(), "TAB33");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

And finally, the page adaptor:

```
package com.example.leesie.bookautism;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by JohnB on 23/08/2017.
 */

public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

A possible solution we were thinking may work would be creating three activities, where each activity has a third of the fragments and simply moving from activity A to activity B once the last picture in activity A is shown. **Would this be a possible solution?**

This seems a rather poor way to write our code, **is there a better solution?**

Also, **are there any resources that may help with our problem?**

Many thanks

### **EDIT**

I was mistaken, all the images *together* have a file size of 4.8MB.

Comment: "The book consists of 35 images which are each about 4.8MB" -- when you say "4.8MB", do you mean that the *file size* is 4.8MB, or that the `Bitmap` in memory consumes 4.8MB?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry for the vagueness, I meant the file size

Comment: In memory, every single bitmap takes **X * Y * 4** (R,G,B,A) bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying one page at a time, you may use a ViewPager for each page that does have it lifecycle and will destroy your unused(unseen) bitmaps.

If you have to show all in case of thumbs, you may load with options.inScale = 4 or more so you take less memory space.

Answer (score 1):

First, a 4.8MB PNG, JPEG, or WebP file is **huge**. The resolution on that image must be in the tens of thousands of pixels per side. There is no Android device with a screen of that resolution. Plus, the decompressed image as a `Bitmap` will be tens or hundreds of MB of heap space, which you will not have. Frankly, I have difficulty believing that you can get 16 loaded before you run into an `OutOfMemoryError`.

So, the first thing that you need to decide is: what is the point of having such a high-resolution image? Right now, you are using an `ImageView`, which means your first task is to **reduce the resolution of those images to something reasonable**. 1080p (1920x1080, give or take depending on the desired aspect ratio) would be a reasonable starting point, or perhaps lower depending upon your target audience.

Next, you seem to have these images as drawable resources. If so, make sure that they are in `res/drawable-nodpi/` or possibly `res/drawable-anydpi/`, not any other drawable directory. Ideally, don't have them as resources at all, but use assets or something else so that you completely control the memory management.

You might also reconsider the choice of media format, switching to HTML. For example, [my main book](https://commonsware.com/Android) is published as an APK file, and in less disk space than your app needs, I have over 4,500 pages of material, including several hundred screenshots and other images.

> Would this be a possible solution?

Not really. Your problem is not with the fragments directly. Your problem is with the images, particularly since you are using resources. Just because you use a second activity does not cause the first activity's memory to magically free up.

> This seems a rather poor way to write our code, is there a better solution?

You do not indicate how you are implementing the tabs. If you are using something based on a `ViewPager`, make sure that you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or some other `PagerAdapter` implementation that does not hold onto everything in memory. You need to ensure that some of these images get out of memory ASAP, and one way to do that is to ensure that the `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter` can let go of pages as the user navigates away.